# Detect even in multiple input in python

Tags: python, split, numbers

i make this code for detect, is user input have even or odd number.

```
a=integer(input('input multiple number : '))`\
if a %2==0:`\
   print('have even number')`\
else:`\
    print('have odd number')`\
```

i want to put multiple numbers and separate them by spaces

its just allow user for input 1 number, so I wanna make code for multiple input, so I just adding .split()

```
a=integer(input('input multiple number : ')).split()`
```

but it goes error because split() cannot work on integer, and I just make input without integer(), my operator doesn't work, please help :")

Comment: Please, edit your question to fix code formatting. Don't use inline formatting. This will also fix the indentation.

Comment: Also, what is `integer()`? A custom function, or do you mean `int()`?

Comment: yes, i mean int(), i have some trouble for write that on question section

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting  `integer` at the input, try putting it when you are evaluating `a`.

for example:

```py
if int(a)%2==0:
  print("even")
```

Also, `int()` is what you are looking for, not `integer()`.

Comment: @Gaga no problem. That's what this site is for.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax to convert to a string input to an integer:

```
Input_variable = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> numbers = input('Enter multiple numbers: ')
Enter multiple numbers: 2 4 3 5 6 7 8 9 34 54
>>> even = []
>>> odd = []
>>> numbers
'2 4 3 5 6 7 8 9 34 54'
>>> for number in numbers.split():
...     if int(number) % 2 == 0:
...             even.append(int(number))
...     else:
...             odd.append(int(number))
...
>>> even
[2, 4, 6, 8, 34, 54]
>>> odd
[3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> print(f'List {even} contains only even nummbers')
List [2, 4, 6, 8, 34, 54] contains only even nummbers
>>> print(f'List {odd} contains only odd numbers')
List [3, 5, 7, 9] contains only odd numbers
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, this is almost exact same as i wonder.
but, can we make it only one sentence for "even number" or "odd number"

Comment: I've edited my answer. To have only one line you need to separate the even from odd numbers and put them into their own lists. Does this helps?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have user enter multiple numbers you can do like this

```
a=input('input multiple number : ').split()
intArray = [int(val) for val in a]
print (intArray)
```

output

```
input multiple number : 1 2 3 4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: thank your sir, this is help me :D